# Equivalent of Visual Studio WordLight add-in for RAD Studio XE2

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, syntax-highlighting, delphi-xe2

Do you know if there is an equivalent of [WordLight](http://code.google.com/p/wordlight/) but for RAD Studio XE2 ? I have to work on some legacy code in Delphi, so this would help a lot.

What this add-in basically does is highlight every occurrence of current mouse selection, which is really useful when you want to check who uses what variable and you're working on a portion of code you know nothing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CNWizard](http://cnpack.org) pack has source highlight add-on, that includes the feature.

[image: Source Highlight Enhancements]

Answer (score 10):

The RAD Studio XE2 includes that feature, just select(highlight ) the word then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and finally press the Down arrow twice, just like is shown in this image.

[image]

Comment: That solution is not fast enough.